# Instantiating classes from a jar that implement a common interface, and then assigning the instance to the interface causes ClassCastException

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

This is a classloader issue that I am struggling with. I understand the root cause of the issue (different classloaders), but I'm not sure about the best way to fix it.

I have project with some common interfaces; let's call it `api`. I have two other projects called `runner` and `module` that both use `api` as a dependency.

The job of `runner` is to dynamically load a `module` artifact (from a jar; it's a fat one that includes its dependencies) and then execute it. `runner` expects `module` to provide certain concrete implementations from `api`. To make sure that classes from different versions of `module.jar` don't clobber each other, I create a new classloader with a URL to `module.jar`, and set the parent classloader to the classloader of the class that loads and processes `module.jar`. This works without any issues.

The problem arose when I used `runner` as a dependency inside a webapp (a spring boot app to be specific), and quickly found that I couldn't load some classes from `module.jar` because they conflict with classes that already exist in the current classpath (from other dependencies in the webapp).

Since `module.jar` really only needs the classes from `api`, I thought that I could create a new `URLClassLoader` (without a parent) that only has classes from `api.jar`, and then use that as the parent classloader when I load up the module. This is where I started running into trouble:

```
CommonInterface commonInterface = null;
Class<CommonInterface> commonInterfaceClass = null;

ClassLoader myClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(moduleJarURL, apiClassesClassLoader);

//...
//...

//clazz is a concrete implementation from module.jar
if(myClassLoader.loadClass(CommonInterface.class.getName()).isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    commonInterfaceClass = clazz; 
}

commonInterface = commonInterfaceClass.newInstance(); //ClassCastException
```

I understand that my original problem is due to the fact that the classloader first checks to see if the class has already been loaded before attempting to load it, which meant that when it was resolved using the name from `module.jar`, it was linking against an incompatible version of the class.

What's a good way to deal with this issue? Instead of creating a URL classloader that only has classes from `api`, does it make sense to create my own implementation that delegates to the parent only if the requested class is one from `api`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this question with my solution. I was able to solve this issue by creating a custom class-loader that extends `URLClassLoader`. This classloader does not have a parent.

I then overrode `loadClass` to control how classes were being loaded. I first check to see if the class exists in `module.jar`. If so, I load it from there. Otherwise, I load it using the current classloader. Since my custom classloader doesn't have a parent, it can load classes from `module.jar` even if they were already loaded by the main classloader, because they do not exist in my custom classloader's hierarchy.

The basic approach was like this:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    private final ClassLoader mainClassLoader = MyClassLoader.class.getClassLoader();
    private final Set<String> moduleClasses;

    private MyClassLoader(URL url) {
        super(new URL[]{ url });
        try {
            JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            this.moduleClasses = connection.getJarFile().stream()
                .map(JarEntry::getName)
                .filter(name -> name.endsWith(".class"))
                .map(name -> name.replace(".class", "").replaceAll("/", "."))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unexpected error while reading module jar: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public static MyClassLoader newInstance(JarFile libraryJar) {
        try {
            return new MyClassLoader(new URL(String.format("jar:file:%s!/", libraryJar.getName())));
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Path to module jar could not be converted into proper URL: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if(moduleClasses.contains(name)) {
            Class<?> clazz = findLoadedClass(name);
            if(clazz != null) {
                return clazz;
            } else {
                return findClass(name);
            }
        } else {
            return mainClassLoader.loadClass(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have loaded `CommonInterface` from two different class loaders. Classes with the same name but different class loaders are different classes to the JVM. (Even if the classes are 100% identical in the .class file - the problem is not incompatibility but the fact that they're from different class loaders)

If you do a

```
System.out.println(CommonInterface.class == myClassLoader.loadClass(CommonInterface.class.getName()));
```

You'll find that this prints `false`.

The way your create your classloader:

```
ClassLoader myClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(moduleJarURL, apiClassesClassLoader);
```

.. would only work if `apiClassesClassLoader` is also a parent class loader of the class that contains this code.

You could try:

```
ClassLoader myClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(moduleJarURL, 
                                                       getClass().getClassLoader());
```

But from your description (it's a "fat" jar that contains its own dependencies) and the intricacies of the web classloader (child first) this may not solve your problem.

In that case, the only solution is to make your module jar "lean" to ensure that you only load each class once with one class loader only.